# ng-grid: Service Called Twice On Initial Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Using ng-grid with server side sorting and paging.  It works great, with one caveat: the initial rendering makes two calls to get data from my service.

I'm not sure how easy (or hard) this would be to replicate in a jsFiddle or plunker.

Here is my controller code:

```
function reportQueueController($scope, $location, reportDataService) {

    function init() {
        $scope.state = {};
    }    

    $scope.setPagingData = function (data) {
        $scope.reportQueueList = data.Data;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.TotalItems;
    };

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal === oldVal) return;
        getPagedDataAsync();
    }, true);

    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [25, 50, 100, 'All'],
        pageSize: 25,
        currentPage: 1
    };

    $scope.$watch('gridOptions.ngGrid.config.sortInfo', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal === oldVal) return;
        $scope.state.sortField = newVal.fields[0];
        $scope.state.sortDirection = newVal.directions[0];
        $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = 1;
        getPagedDataAsync();
    }, true);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'reportQueueList',
        enablePaging: true,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        showFooter: true,
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        enableSorting: true,
        useExternalSorting: true,
        sortInfo: { fields: ['CustomerName'], directions: ['asc'] },

        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'CustomerName', displayName: 'Customer' },
            { field: 'ParentCustomerName', displayName: 'Parent' },
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Report Name' },
            { field: 'Emails', displayName: 'Email Recipients', cellTemplate: emailCellTemplate },
            { cellTemplate: editCellTemplate, width: '50px' }
        ]
    };

    function getPagedDataAsync() {
        console.log('in get data');  //this get logged twice
        reportDataService.getReportQueueList($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.state.emailAddress, $scope.state.reportSearch, $scope.state.sortField, $scope.state.sortDirection).then(function(data) {
            $scope.setPagingData(data);
        });
    };

    init();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you calling `getPagedDataAsync()` once in each `$watch`?

Comment: Yes.  Is that the problem?  I also notice that when I am not on page 1 and I sort, I get two calls because I set the page # to 1.  I'm not sure how to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, angular is going to call `$watch` twice during the `$digest` cycle.  It uses dirty checking to see if values are changing. [This is a great post about it](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It makes sense, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.  I believe I need watches on both paging and sorting changes to detect changes to the grid.  I can't find an end-to-end example on using server side sorting/paging with ng-grid. I will continue to tinker/search, but if you have any suggestions I would certainly appreciate them.

Comment: @PhilSandler one really dirty way to get around the mandatory initial `$watch` call is to use a flag on the scope and check it in your `$watch` before you call `getPagedDataAsync`. if it's false, set the flag to true and return immediately, if it's true, let it continue on to call `getPagedDataAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular is going to call your watch at least twice, maybe more due to dirty processing, per $digest cycle you could use debounce.  This is similar to what windows event listeners sometimes do.  underscore (http://underscorejs.org) and lo-dash (http://lodash.com) both offer a `_.debounce()` you can use right out of the box.

`_.debounce()` allows you to say that a function should run, at most, once every per the specified number of milliseconds- no matter how many times the function is actually called.  So you might do something like:

```
var checkSortData = _.debounce(function(e) {
    $scope.state.sortField = newVal.fields[0];
    $scope.state.sortDirection = newVal.directions[0];
    $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = 1;
    getPagedDataAsync();    
}, 500); // Run no more than once every 500 milliseconds
```

As you'd imagine underscore uses $timeout to do this, so you could write your own debounce if you preferred.

Using debounce could help with performance/server load too by minimizing server calls.

But rather than paying the performance price of polling the server to see if it has updated you might also consider using something like http://socket.io.  Then you wouldn't have to poll using a watch, you can just attach an event listener on the client side.  Here's an article on using socket.io with Angular written by Brian Ford:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, check if you are using unobtrusive js file twice, like

```
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Or the same file is adding twice.